# Примерчик не так работает xml, jQuery

Tags: xml, jquery

Есть следующий Javascript-код:

```
var xml = "<note><elements><button id='1' name='btn1'/><input id='3' name='inp1'/><mycontrol id='7' name='myc1'></mycontrol></elements></note>";
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$('elements *', xmlDoc).each(function(i, el){
    alert(el.id);
    alert(el.name);
});
```

el.id выводятся, а el.name - нет, пишет "undefined". Как получить такое свойство?

И ещё... Как понять, что button - это и есть button, а input - это и есть input???

Answer (score 3):

```
 alert($(el).prop("tagName"));
 alert($(el).attr("name"));
```